# How to compute the mean of a conditional linear gaussian distribution

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, bayesian-network

In a bayes net context consider the following covariance matrix
 where G is the child node and D and E are continuous parents

```
           G         D         E
G 11.4038771 0.8944238 9.3671434
D  0.8944238 0.2937604 0.2322106
E  9.3671434 0.2322106 8.8262010
```

with

```
36.6174413683 #mean of G
[7.35806706, 15.06258672] #mean of D and E respectively
```

I know that the equation used is

```
μa|b = μa +Σab Σbb−1(xb −μb)
```

But I am just having some trouble to compute the conditional linear gaussian mean with more than one continuous parent, so please someone show how to compute it  with some clear steps.

Notice: this is the clgaussian.test dataset from bnlearn R library.

Comment: You can still use this equation `μa|b = μa +Σaa Σab−1(xb −μb)` even when you have more than one parent...

Comment: @ZERO clear steps please

Comment: Actually, that formula is incorrect.  The correct one should read: `µa|b = µa + ∑ab ∑bb-1 (xb - µb)`.

Comment: @Vimal I have edited my question with the correct formula..it was an honest typo I swear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wiki has a clear description of how to compute the conditional mean and conditional variance:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions

If your covariance matrix is:

$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{dd} & \sigma_{de} & \sigma_{dg} \\ \sigma_{ed} & \ldots & \\ \sigma_{gd} & \ldots \end{bmatrix}$

You can compute (there's a mistake in your conditional mean formula):

$\mu_{G|D,E=(d,e)} = 
\mu_G +
\begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{gd} & \sigma_{ge}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{dd} & \sigma_{de} \\ \sigma_{ed} & \sigma_{ee}\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix} d - \mu_d \\ e - \mu_e\end{bmatrix}
$